# mongodb dataypes when importing

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I want to clone a collection to a new collection, remove all the documents, and then import new documents from a csv file.  When I do the copy using copyTo everything works fine.  The datatypes are copied over from the source collection to the new collection.  However, after I remove all the documents from the new collection and import from the csv, the datatypes are lost.  The datatypes from my source csv are already setup to match what is in the source collection I copied from.

- Is there a way to preserve the datatypes after removing all documents from a collection?
- How can I copy the datatypes from my csv when importing? For example my date columns show as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new collection doesn't have a fixed schema so documents added don't have to be similar unless you've created the collection using the `validator` option. You can also add validation to an existing collection.  See [Document Validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/) in the MongoDB manual.

Comment: Great. This helps and adds a layer of validation that I wanted, but how can I "copy or extract" the schema from a collection so that I can apply it to a new collection (if such a thing is possible)?  I'm coming from a sql background and I'm trying to understand if there is any equivalent to scripting a table in sql.

Comment: We don't use the validation feature so I don't know if there's a way to create a validation schema from an existing document. We started with MongoDB v2 (validation is a v3.2+ feature)...I don't think we'll add validation to our collections because we love the flexibility in what we write to the database. Our server code is Java so we have no issues with extra fields or incorrect data types (because we persist Java objects). It's nice to be able to change what we persist without having to reconfigure the collection. Our domain is somewhat fluid so our data model often changes in small ways.

Comment: The point of my previous comment (which ran out of space) is to suggest skipping validation if possible. We migrated our application from a relational database and haven't regretted it once. We are able to adapt to required and requested changes so much faster than before. For example, changing a field from a single value to an array is trivial now...coming from an sql background you know what a pain that is in a relational database.  Code-enforced constraints work for us (we've had no data integrity issues) but may not for you, of course.

Comment: I see. Makes sense. Thanks a lot.